# Optimize compiling of large TypeScript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript3.0

I have an autogenerated TypeScript file, that *only* exports an array of 65,000 small objects. The auto-generation is done on an ad-hoc basis, but the compilation is done each time the project is built. Since most of the build-time is spent on compiling this particular file, I would like to optimise it a bid.

This optimisation is primarily a good idea since the file is only being changed 1-3 times a year. Some other parts depend on this file, so I do not think I am able not to compile it.

Is it possible to somehow not compile a file, if it has not been changed, while still being able to reference it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--watch` compiler option to incrementally build the project as files change. While this will save time on subsequent build, the first one will still be slow.

A better option might be to compile the file individually (when you generate), and generate a `d.ts`(using the `"declaration": true` option), which will probably be smaller and use the `js` file in your actual project instead. You could also keep the `ts` file in the project and use `"exclude": ["file.ts"]` in your `tsconfig.json` to nto build the fiel every time.

Comment: I am using `--watch` currently while developing, but some external factors require me to rebuild the whole project multiple times a day. I will look into referencing the js file instead.

Comment: @Hedam then you best option is to exclude the `ts` file from your main, and build it separately.